# Group by Issue GreenPlum

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group, greenplum

I want to do a group by in a table with ~300 columns.
There are orders and their status is updated for the next 30 days.
I want to pick the order with the max(update_time).
So my query is something like this:

```
select order_num,status,order_date,max(update_date)     from orders
where order_date = '2021-07-01'
     and update_date between '2021-07-01' and '2021-08-01'
 group by 'primary_key';
```

Is there a way to write the query without adding an aggregate function on all 300 columns?

Comment: grouping by pk doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are looking for this :

```
select * from (
   select * , row_number() over (partition by order_num order by update_date desc) rn
   from orders
) t
where rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to pick the order with the max(update_time).

I think you want:

```
select o.*
from orders o
order by o.update_time
offset 0 row fetch first 1 row only;
```

The `fetch first` clause is to fetch one row only.  You don't specify your database, but your database might use `limit` or `select top` or something else.